# Spin implied by the Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

I've come across a derivation of the fact that the Dirac equation described particles of spin $\frac{1}{2}$ that roughly goes as follows: start with the Hamiltonian ansatz $H=\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot \boldsymbol p+\beta m$ where $\boldsymbol\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the usual Dirac basis matrices and calculate its commutator with the angular momentum, which should, by Lorentz invariance, be zero: however we find $$[\boldsymbol L,H]=i\boldsymbol\alpha\times\boldsymbol p\ne 0. $$ If we define an operator $\boldsymbol S=s\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol\sigma & 0 \\ 0 & \boldsymbol\sigma\end{pmatrix}$ and calculate $$[\boldsymbol S,H]=-2si\boldsymbol\alpha\times \boldsymbol p $$we find that $s$ must be $\frac{1}{2}$. I set out to see using the same argument what I could obtain from the Klein-Gordon equation. Taking the time derivative of the Schroedinger equation gives (assuming $H$ to be time-independent) $$(-\partial_t^2-H^2)\psi=0 $$
from which we can see that the Klein-Gordon Hamiltonian is $H=-\boldsymbol\nabla^2+m^2$. The commutator with angular momentum is $$[\boldsymbol L, H]=[\boldsymbol q\times \boldsymbol p,\boldsymbol p^2]=\varepsilon_{ijk}[q_ip_j,p_lp_l]\boldsymbol e_k=0 $$
provided I haven't messed up the calculation. So, this should mean that the Klein-Gordon equation described particles with spin $0$, and indeed it does, but it should also describe particles with spin $1$. How can I modify this argument to see that?

Comment: Every free field satisfies the KG equation spinning or not. However, spinning fields satisfy extra equations as well so the KG equation doesn't uniquely describe them.

Comment: @Prahar Is there a Hamiltonian analogous to $H=\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot\boldsymbol p+\beta m$ for particles with spin $1$?

Comment: Yes, it's called the Proca equation: $\partial^\mu V_{\mu \nu} + m^2 V_\nu = 0$. But with your calculation you should get something like $H = \sqrt{- \Delta + m^2}$ right? But this is usually not done because if you were to expand the square root, then your equation of motion contains higher-order derivatives. So the Klein-Gordan equation can not be written in a Schrödinger form as you have done.

Comment: Wait why do you say that the Klein-Gordon equation should describe particles with spin-1? I normally think of the Klein-Gordon equation as applying to a scalar field, you need to look at Maxwell's equations or the Proca equations to describe a massless or massive spin-1 particle, respectively.

Comment: As @Prahar has pointed out, ANY free field satisfies the Klein-Gordan equation. It pretty much just states $p^2 = m^2$ only in a differential form. You can see that easily for the Dirac equation by multiplying with $(i \not{\partial} + m)$. Same holds for the Proca equation, which just combines the Klein-Gordan equation and the Lorentz-gauge condition. $\partial^\mu \partial^\nu V_{\mu \nu} + m^2 \partial^\nu V_\nu = m^2 \partial^\nu V_\nu = 0 \Rightarrow  \partial^\mu V_{\mu \nu} + m^2 V_\nu = (\square + m^2) V_\nu$.

Comment: @Prahar I see, thank you. I'm a bit sad there seems to be no way to extend the argument to spin $1$, since it works so well for spin $0$ and $1/2$.

Comment: Your argument did not work for scalar fields because as pointed then no particle would have spin since they all satisfy the Klein-Gordan equation.

Comment: @tomtom1-4 You're right. Then how do I interpret the fact that $[H,\boldsymbol L]=0$ for the Klein-Gordan Hamiltonian?

Comment: As I said before, you can't extract $H$ from the Klein-Gordan equation. You would need a first-order time derivative on one side and you can only achieve that if you take the square root. This however introduces terms with $p^4, p^6, \ldots$ which is unphysical. So the problem is that there is no unique hamiltonian.